# Eclipse-RCP: Hide lines of text permanently, keep correct line numbers

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have text files which contain code inside an Editor. The user can run an analysis on a certain part of his code, which will result in a set of lines which should be hidden. Next I want to present the user with only the remaining lines, but with *correct linenumbers*, as from the original document. Possible solutions I thought of:

1. Open a new Editor which does not contain the hidden lines, but *somehow* still has correct line numbers
2. Hide the lines in the original editor, and offer a button for the user to 'unhide'. Probably a similar solution required as in 1.

I don't really know how to go about this. Folds would be a weird solution, because they can be unfolded individually, and seem to be more semantically tied to things like methods or classes. Also, simply creating a new document without the hidden lines results in wrong linenumbers.

Comment: Is this editor an existing editor such as the Java editor or something you will write? For an editor that you write you should be able to control the line number ruler, for an existing editor it would be much harder.

Comment: It is an already written editor, but not an existing one(like the Java editor), so I can change what I want/need. I looked into the line number ruler, but couldn't see an easy/intended way to skip certain line numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ProjectionViewer` and reflection to invoke the private method `ProjectionViewer.collapse(int offset int length)`. This method is only used internally to hide a certain portion of the text, by manipulating the `ProjectionDocument` (see http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html).

After this, folding text in the editor using the annotations(the little +/- icons) WILL break everything, so this solution and regular folding are mutually exclusive.